# in snakemake, for two inputs, expand pairwise combination of a vector

Tags: snakemake

I am new to Snakemake and have a problem in Snakemake  expand function.

First, I need to have a group of combinations and use them as base to expand another vector upon them  with pair-wise elements combinations of it.
Lets say the set for the pairwise combination is

```
setC=["A","B","C","D"]
```

I get the partial group as follows:

```
part_group1 = expand("TEMPDIR/{setA}_{setB}_", setA = config["setA"], setB = config["setB"]
```

Then, (if that is OK), I used this partial group, to expand another set with its pairwise combinations. But I am not sure how to expand pairwise combinations of setC as seen below. It is obviously not correct; just written to clarify the question. Also, how to input the name of the expanded estimator from shell?

```
rule get_performance:
input:
    xdata1 = TEMPDIR + part_group1 +"{setC}.rda"
    xdata2 = TEMPDIR + part_group1 +"{setC}.rda"
    estimator1= {estimator}
output:
    results = TEMPDIR + "result_" + part_group1 +{estimator}_{setC}_{setC}.txt"
params:
    Rfile = FunctionDIR + "function.{estimator}.R"
shell:
    "Rscript {params.Rfile} {input.xdata1} {input.xdata12} {input.estimator1} "
    "{output.results}"
```

Comment: The `expand` function is using the `product` of its arguments. In cases where this is not suitable, it is often a good idea to write custom Python code that does what you want, e.g., use a list comprehension or a generator function.

Answer (score 4):

The `expand` function will return a list of the product of the variables used. For example, if

```
setA=["A","B"]
setB=["C","D"]
```

then

```
expand("TEMPDIR/{setA}_{setB}_", setA = config["setA"], setB = config["setB"]
```

will give you:

```
["TEMPDIR/A_C_","TEMPDIR/A_D_","TEMPDIR/B_C_","TEMPDIR/B_D_"]
```

Your question is not very clear on what you want to achieve but I'll have a guess.
If you want to make pairwise combinations of setC:

```
import itertools
combiC=list(itertools.combinations(setC, 2))
combiList=list()
for c in combiC:
    combiList.append(c[0]+"_"+c[1])
```

the you (probably) want the files:

```
rule all:
    input: expand(TEMPDIR + "/result_{A}_{B}_estim{estimator}_combi{C}.txt",A=setA, B=setB, estimator=estimators, C=combiList)
```

I'm putting some words like "estim" and "combi" not to confuse the wildcards here. I do not know what the list or set "estimators" is supposed to be but I suppose you have declared it above.
Then your rule `get_performance`:

```
rule get_performance:
    input: 
           xdata1 = TEMPDIR + "/{A}_{B}_{firstC}.rda",
           xdata2 = TEMPDIR + "/{A}_{B}_{secondC}.rda"
    output:
           TEMPDIR + "/result_{A}_{B}_estim{estimator}_combi{firstC}_{secondC}.txt"
    params:
           Rfile = FunctionDIR + "/function.{estimator}.R"
    shell:
           "Rscript {params.Rfile} {input.xdata1} {input.xdata2} {input.estimator} {output.results}"
```

Again, this is a guess since you haven't defined all the necessary items.

Comment: Thank you. I wanted to give it a try but not clear how to get firstC and secondC.

Comment: firstC and secondC will be set by the combinations from setC I describe above. For example if `setC=["X","Y"]` then my list combiList will contain `"X_Y"` and in the "all" rule the file listed will be `"TEMPDIR/result_{A}_{B}_estim{estimator}_combiX_Y.txt`. The wildcards firstC and secondC can then be applied in rule "get_performance"